# How to group items by internal list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group a list of `User` by their according `Group`.
A user can be in multiple groups.

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

The BusinessLogic returns me a `List<User>`.
Instead of Users have their Groups, I need to reform this list so Groups contains the Users.

Example:
**Group 1**:
 - User 1
 - User 2
**Group 2**:
- User 1
- User 3
**Group 3**:
- User 2
- User 3

I'm stuck on which extension method I need to use, so I'm not sure what to search for.
I would assume the `GroupBy` method but after that I'm lost :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` to flatten the nested collections are retrieve tuples of user and it's groups. That way a use containing many groups will result in multiple record. Next group there records by the group and keep the user as the items in the group

```
var result = userList.SelectMany(user => user.Groups.Select(group => (user,group)))
                     .GroupBy(item => item.group, item => item.User);
```

In the current implementation, as the group by is performed on a `Group` object, that object should implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. If you don't want to do so then there exists an overload that also receives an `IEqualityComparer`. For more details see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__).

*Notice the use of Named Tuples. If you are using a C# prior to 7.0 then you can project an anonymous object instead or explicitly initialize a tuple and then also change the way you access properties - `Item1` and `Item2`.*

Answer (score 1):

Solution proposed in the accepted answer does not work. My solution:

```
var result1 = from user in users
              from grp in user.Groups
              group user by grp into pivot
              select pivot;
```

Fixed version of Gilad code:

```
var result = users.SelectMany(user => user.Groups,(user, group)=>(user,group))
                          .GroupBy(item => item.group,item=>item.user);
```

Full code of mine and Gilad:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Group group1 = new Group("Group1");
    Group group2 = new Group("Group2");
    Group group3 = new Group("Group3");
    List<User> users = new List<User>(new User[] {
        new User() { Username = "User1", Groups = new List<Group>(new Group[] { group1,group2})  },
        new User() { Username = "User2", Groups = new List<Group>(new Group[] { group1,group3})  },
        new User() { Username = "User3", Groups = new List<Group>(new Group[] { group2,group3})  }
    });
    var result1 = from user in users
                 from grp in user.Groups
                 group user by grp into pivot
                 select pivot;
    foreach (var r in result1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r.Key.Name);
        foreach (var u in r)
            Console.WriteLine(u.Username);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    var result = users.SelectMany(user => user.Groups.Select(group => (user, group))
              .GroupBy(item => item.group,item=>item.user));
    foreach (var r in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r.Key.Name);
        foreach (var u in r)
            Console.WriteLine(u.Username);
    }


    Console.ReadKey();
}

public class Group : IEquatable<Group>
{
    public Group(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Group other)
    {
        return other.Name == Name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ((Group)obj).Name==Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Output (First comes my code, second Gilad's code output):

```
Group1
User1
User2
Group2
User1
User3
Group3
User2
User3

Group1
User1
Group2
User1
Group1
User2
Group3
User2
Group2
User3
Group3
User3
```

Comment: You are correct that the code did not work as intended, but it set me on the right track.
I which I could accept both answers :)